# ENOENT Error can't find directory of location that exists?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Using FS I am trying to load a directory that exists, however, whenever I try to have it load in the folder, it give me an error that it cannot find it, am I calling the directory wrong?

```
const { readdirSync } = require('fs');

module.exports = (client) => {
  const load = dirs => {
    const commands = readdirSync(`../Commands/${dirs}/`).filter(d => d.endsWith('.js'));
    for(let file of commands) {
      const pull = require(`../Commands/${dirs}/${file}`)
      client.commands.set(pull.config.name, pull)
      if(pull.config.aliases) pull.config.aliases.forEach(a => client.aliases.set(a, pull.config.name))
    }
  }
  [ "Developer", "Fun", "Images", "Info", "Moderation", "Settings", "Utility" ].forEach(x => load(x))
}
```

How the directory looks:

```
Scout Dev
> Core
>> Commands
>>> Developer
>>> Fun
>>> Images
>>> Info
>>> Moderation
>>> Settings
>>> Utility
>> Handlers
>>> commandHandler.js (the main code)
>> Events
```

Error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '../Commands/Developer/'
```

Comment: You need two dots (“..”), as in your code after that. That means “one directory above the one I’m in.

Comment: It gave me the same error as before.

Comment: Please provide the code you run

Comment: Just changed the code for you to be able to check.

Answer (score 0):

In Addressing commands `./`  refer to the same level folder but in your case the main code an command folder are not in the same level so you should use:

```js
readdirSync(__dirname + `/../Commands/${dirs})
```

Actually it works for `dir` part.
for the `require part` you have to make path with some statics
for exmaple:

```
const path = __dirname.replace('Handlers','Commands') +`/${dirs}/${file}`;
const pull = require(path);
```

Comment: It didn't change anything, still same error just with the updated code.

Comment: sorry I fix my answer and test it , now it works fine.